# MySql return type for extract function

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me what would be the type that is returned from MySQL for an extract function

My query would look something like this:

select extract(month from logged_ts) from process_log limit 10;

I want to know the type of month returned , is it Integer or Long

when i tried to check the types by following query

```
select extract(hour from '2016-01-01 05:15:30') as hh, 
       extract(minute from '2016-01-01 05:15:30') as min, 
       extract(second from '2016-01-01 05:15:30') as sec, 
       extract(year from '2016-01-01 05:15:30') as yyyy,
       extract(month from '2016-01-01 05:15:30')as mm, 
       extract(day from '2016-01-01 05:15:30') as dd;

desc extract_time_tbl;
```

I am getting this result:

Output:

```
    hh   int(2) 
    min  int(2) 
    sec  int(2) 
    yyyy int(4) 
    mm   int(2) 
    dd   int(2)
```

I want to know whether the type  would be the same each time i query.

Comment: Yes the type will remain same always

Answer (score 0):

All the sql select method return a result resource, in loosely meaning you can call this a table or multi diamentiona array. When there is only one element in the result, e.g,

```
Select count(id) from table
```

Or

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM "2017-06-15");
```

The return type is one cell table. Use you scripting language to read the result resource (the table) and parse the data.

If you are using php, the following pseudo code can be a help

```
$res = mysqli_query("SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "2017-06-15");");
$ar = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
$val = $ar[0];
```

The data type of value will be string but you can convert it to any of your choice if you know it will be. In the above case the $val will be 6.